# Another exception was thrown: Unexpected null value. Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-container

Here is my code:

```
 class ListItems extends StatelessWidget {
final String child; const ListItems({super.key, required this.child});

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Sizer(builder: ((context, orientation, deviceType) { return Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Container( color: Colors.blueGrey, height: 25.h, child: Text(child), ), ); })); } }
```

Comment: What is the child inside the 'Text' widget? Can you share the code for that?

Comment: PLEASE [Edit and update more  code here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76052074/edit).

Comment: Also format you code by selecting all the code portion by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76052074/edit) and `ctrl and press k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the is `deviceType` is not being passed into the `Sizer` widget in the `ListItems` class. So try providing device type or remove the device parameter from `Sizer` widget.

```
class ListItems extends StatelessWidget {
  final String child;

  const ListItems({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(
      builder: ((context, orientation, [deviceType = DeviceType.mobile]) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: 100,
              maxHeight: 100,
            ),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Center(child: Text(child)),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```